# isp that serves international customers . possible?

Tags: isp

I do not know if it is possible to find an isp, maybe in america or asia, that provides services to international clients i.e clients outside their region, possibly in africa. i believe it is possible. 
can anyone help?

Comment: By ISP do you mean web hosting? I can't see an African ISP offering ADSL to clients in North America.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a worldwide/global satellite ISP. Googling "global satellite isp" turned up a number of results, though you'd have to filter through them to figure out which ones were legit and which ones were shady (a lot of them had pretty sketchy websites, which is always a hit at shadiness IMHO).